# How would de Morgan's law apply to ((A.B)`.B)`

Tags: boolean, algebra

I am at the start of my A-level computing course, but I have gotten stuck on de Morgan's law,
If we have the expression  (pronounced: Not(A And B) And B all Not) How would de Morgan's law apply to that?
And can anyone explain me how you handle the Not(A And B) part when the entire thing is notted?

Thanks in advance

[image: write-up of the formula here]

Comment: Please write the formula down properly.

Comment: Please check the link i have added. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: oh, I have never heard of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `~`, `.` and `v` represent `NOT`, `AND` and `OR` operator respectively. Then we can apply the De Morgans's law as:

`~((A.B).B) = ~(A.B) v ~B
=>          = (~A v ~B) v ~B`

Comment: Great! I forgot that you use basic maths to expand the bracket, Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that there is a mistake on the answer above as the initial formula is wrong (and there is a typo too) - it shouldn't be too hard to spot the mistakes though and get the correct answer for yourself.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for pointing out the error in answer. I just tried to explain how we can apply the De Morgan's law.

Comment: No problem - I see you fixed the typo, but there is still an error in the initial formula - it's good to let the OP work this out for himself though, since that is the whole point of homework.